# Reloading issue with Vanilla JS Router

Tags: javascript, url-routing, single-page-application

i have an issue with a custom Vanilla JS SPA router that I have implemented in my project, the router functions as expected, but if I want to reload, it attempts to reload the current window location, but because that directory doesn't physically exist, it reloads to a 404 page.

Here is the code I use:

```
function load_content(id) {
    // Update text "Content loading for {id}..."
    console.log("Loading page for {" + id + "}");
    
    // Function to load different page
    goToBreadCrumb(id);
}


function push(event) {
    // Set identifier for page
    let id = event;
    // Update Title in Window's Tab
    document.title = 'CorzzoFit: '+ id;
    // Load content for this tab/page
    load_content(id);
    // Finally push state change to the address bar
    window.history.pushState({id}, `${id}`, `${id}`);
}


// Listen for PopStateEvent (Back or Forward buttons are clicked)
window.addEventListener("popstate", event => {
    // Grab the history state id
    let stateId = event.state.id;
    // Show clicked id in console (just for fun)
    console.log("stateId = ", stateId);
    // Load content for this tab/page
    load_content(stateId);
});
```

It's fairly simple, the first function changes/loads the page to display, the second function is a "manual control" to choose what page to load, and the third function "automatically" chooses what page to load by listening to the window pop state.

How can I make it so when I reload the site, it either goes back to the root (index.php), or simply reload the current page?

Comment: Depending on what kind of server you are running you should add some configuration (server side) that loads your index.php regardless of the url.

Comment: I guess I could set the last page visited in the session storage, and once it reloads set a listener to check what page they had and if session is still active to actually go there, but it doesn't seam to be the best way, is that how react router o angular manage it?

Comment: That won't work because you'd still have to place that script on every page. Do you know anything about your server configuration? Is it running apache? Or nginx?

Comment: (the problem is that your browser tries to actually load the url (on page reload) but it doesn't exist, so you would need to tell it to serve the same page on every request, your js will take over from there)

Comment: It is on every page, because it's an SPA, single page "application" there is only one file the site has no need to actually reload, me using the router, so it should be a viable option, @GijsBeijer but how could I change the url before the site reloads? I tried with "beforeunload", but had no luck...

Comment: I know you are making an SPA and your code works as long as you start at the root of the website. that's exactly why the problem occurs when you reload the page. At that point your browser will look for that url but it does not exist. To fix this you will have to tell your server to always load the same file no matter what the url is you are typing. That's the only way to get this to work. (Or you'll have to use hashed urls but I'm guessing that's not what you want).

Comment: Did you get it to work, and do you understand my point now? Again if you need help with the server config let me know what kind of server you're running your app on and I can send you an example

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, busy work... Yes, I got it to work, the server I am working on is Apache running with Plesk. I made some script thats checks your session storage for a token that I generate when you login, and on reload, the site goes to the base index file, so If you had an active session, it loggs you back in, and takes you to the same page you where viewing

Comment: Great to hear that!

Comment: Hello @GijsBeijer, I am totally lost in a similar situation but with an express router. Would you be so kind to help? Thanks!